Can I create a printer-friendly version of my email in Marketing Cloud?
<!-- BOOKING INFO - 1x2 -->
<tr>
<td class="" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 20px 0 0;">
<table class="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width: 95%;">
<tr>
<td width="50%" class="" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 15px;">
<img class="mobi_hero_icon" src="https://image.carnivalcruiselineemail.com/lib/fe9513727761047c7c/m/1/c0698a32-01b4-48cc-be92-82dc9d80efb8.png" alt="Ship" border="0" style="height: auto; width: 50px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #dc1125; font-weight: bold;"/>
</td>
<td width="50%" class="" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 15px;">
<img class="mobi_hero_icon" src="https://image.carnivalcruiselineemail.com/lib/fe9513727761047c7c/m/1/8ce0d2f0-b4dd-4222-9c34-a5b1f7c81051.png" alt="Room View" border="0" style="height: auto; width: 50px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #dc1125; font-weight: bold;"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hero_icon_title" align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: bold; color: #10559a; padding: 5px 0 0 0;">
%%=v(@ShipName)=%%
<br>
%%=v(@SailDateFormat)=%%

</td>
<td class="hero_icon_title" align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: bold; color: #10559a; padding: 5px 0 0 0;">
%%=ProperCase(@RoomView)=%%
<br>
%%=ProperCase(@AccessLevel)=%%
</td>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- //BOOKING INFO - 1x2 -->


<!-- BOOKING INFO - 1x2 -->
<tr>
<td class="" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 20px 0;">
<table class="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width: 95%;">
<tr>
<td width="50%" class="" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 15px;">
<img class="mobi_hero_icon" src="https://image.carnivalcruiselineemail.com/lib/fe9513727761047c7c/m/1/ac48561d-a8bc-446c-ac04-2cdba009c118.png" alt="Cabin Number" border="0" style="height: auto; width: 50px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #dc1125; font-weight: bold;"/>
</td>
<td width="50%" class="" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 15px;">
<img class="mobi_hero_icon" src="https://image.carnivalcruiselineemail.com/lib/fe9513727761047c7c/m/1/94f319a5-d42f-448d-8836-03d3fc9aca5a.png" alt="Dining" border="0" style="height: auto; width: 50px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #dc1125; font-weight: bold;"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hero_icon_title" align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: bold; color: #10559a; padding: 5px 0 0 0;">
Room #%%=v(@CabinNum)=%%
</td>
<td class="hero_icon_title" align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: bold; color: #10559a; padding: 5px 0 0 0;">
%%=ProperCase(@DiningConfirmedUI)=%%
</td>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
<!-- //BOOKING INFO - 1x2 -->


If I understand your query correctly, you’re looking to generate a print-friendly version of your email. To achieve this, you can utilize the @media print CSS rule, which applies specific styles only when the page is printed or viewed in a print preview. This ensures that these styles do not interfere with the email’s display on screens. Although I haven’t personally tested this in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, you might find useful guidance in the following resource: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699436/media-print-css.
@media print {
    body {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #000000;
    }

    /* Add your custom print styles here */

    .no-print {
        display: none;
    }
}

Print Styles:
The @media print section is designed for print-specific styles, allowing you to adjust font sizes, icon sizes, and other elements to ensure that the content is easily readable and properly formatted on paper.
The .no-print class can be used to hide any elements that are not needed in the printed version.
General Styles:
Keep your regular email styles for digital displays separate from print styles to ensure that your email looks consistent and well-designed in both formats.
